# How do I transfer dataset from one schema to another?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I recently made a huge error at work by updating the production database with wrong data.  I created a schema against a production database, and created a table.  I then got a copy of the table with only the data I replaced from the test server.  example, I replaced all the users with type 6  in a column with type 45 in that column, on the production server.  I now, have a copy of the only the data with type 6 in that specific column, which was close to 4000 users.  I created a schema in the production server, and created the same name table, and copied the dataset in my new schema.

My question is how do I replace the datasets, on the production database, that I mistakenly replaced 6 from 45, with the dataset from my schema database table, which only contains the users with 6 in that column?

I know I can do it manually, but it will take forever, and hope somebody can help me do it really quickly, and painlessly, SUCH AS A STORED PROCEDURE. Since I been in the dirt for these couple days?  Thank you

Comment: Do you have flashback enabled on your db?

Comment: You might try an `as of timestamp` flashback query, however if it's been a couple of days you might be out of luck.

Comment: It happened yesterday.  I tried the flashback command and got couple errors.  ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1, ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P005, and ORA-01555: Snapshot too old: rollback segment number 6 with name "_SYSSMU6_422204433$" too small.  any ideas?  Thaks

Comment: Perhaps it's none of my or our business, but:  Did you **report** your mistake to your supervisor? Or are you just trying to fix it on your own before it is discovered? As a former partner in a firm I can tell you we would fire someone on the spot for making a mistake like this and not reporting it immediately. Then: don't try to cover up your mistake if you aren't 100% sure what you are doing; chances are you'll make the whole thing a lot worse, in which case you will almost surely be fired.

Comment: Yes I reported it. I was told the dba has a log of everything and "could" go back to time of update and then run all the database commands again from that point.  But it might take a week, bc the database server is in another state, and he would have to fill out a work order and all this other bureaucracy of levels.  Says it happens before and would be better to just fix it on our end.   I still feel horrible about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rman to restore that particular table using alternative table_name and remap it actual table name.

recover table scott.new_table
until time "to_date('08/17/2014 21:01:15','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')"
auxiliary destination '/stage/PSES/'
remap table scott.new_table:actual_table;
or
recover table new_table_name
until SCN 1853267
auxiliary destination '/stage/PSES/'
remap table scott.new_table:actual_table;

Answer (score 0):

If you have toad installed and you have the old data in dev db or if you can create the same old data then toad is having option like compare the 2 tables in 2 different schemas or 2 different databases and as a result of compare it will give you the insert or update statement which you need to execute on any one of the schema or db to sync both the tables.

Also even from the table data output(grid tab in toad),you can select the specific data and you can generate dml automatically from toad and you can use that script and insert the same in production table

Comment: I do not have toad installed and probably would not be given permission to install that on the server.  I do have one question I try to use flashback and got errors ora00604, ora12801, and ora01555.  Would you know what it might be

Comment: It seems flashback logs are overwritten and you can't flashback to that particular timesetamp.